# angularjs $watch watchExpression with promise is going into infinite digest loop

Tags: angularjs, typescript, localforage

angularjs watch method with watchExpression returning a promise.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
var promise = MyService.getMethod();
promise.then(function(value){
  return value;
})
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
console.log("new value:", newValue);
});
```

Typescript call to the method with promise.

```
public getMethod(): angular.IPromise<any> {
  var deferred: angular.IDeferred<any>   = this.$q.defer();
  localforage.getItem(‘key’).then(function(value) {
    deferred.resolve(value);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    deferred.reject();
    console.log(err);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to return the "value" from the localforage promise in MyService to return to the $watch watchExpression function.

Comment: You have `deferred` antipattern. You can just `return localforage.getItem('key')` with same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localforage.bind](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage/blob/master/src/angular-localForage.js#L354) to directly bind storage value to scope:

```
localforage.bind($scope, {key: 'key', scopeKey: 'scKey'});
```

And use two-way binded `$scope.scKey`.

Comment: I am using http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/ this not the anuglar one, will surely try the one you suggested.